# How to get data from the consumer loop to another class in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am creating a microservice for sending bulk emails. I am getting the user name, email id of the user, the subject and the body of the email, etc through an API. I am using producer & consumer loops and also validating the contents of the API. I need help in getting the verified data from the EmailBuffer class to the EmailServices class where i am sending the email.

EmailConsumer class

```
package com.webservices.worker;

import com.webservices.buffer.EmailBuffer;

public class EmailConsumer implements Runnable {
    private EmailBuffer buffer;

    public EmailConsumer(EmailBuffer buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }
    
    //Consumer Loop
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                buffer.get();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EmailBuffer class

```
package com.webservices.buffer;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import com.webservices.model.EmailModel;

//Shared class used by threads
public class EmailBuffer<EmailModel> {
    // LinkedBlockingQueue
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<EmailModel> emailLinkedBlockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<EmailModel>(1);

    public void get() {
        // retrieve from LinkedBlockingQueue (take elements from the head of the queue)
        //called by consumer
        try {
            EmailModel emailData = emailLinkedBlockingQueue.take();
            System.out.println("Consumer received - " + emailData);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void put(EmailModel user) {
        try {
            //called by producer
            // putting in LinkedBlockingQueue (add elements at the tail of the queue)
            emailLinkedBlockingQueue.put(user);
            System.out.println("Producer produced - " + user);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

EmailServices Class

```
package com.webservices.services;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

//blueprint for creating thread
public class EmailServices implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Preparing to send the email");
        String recipient = "abc@gmail";
        String subject = "Welcome message";
        String message = "Hello,\nThis email has been sent using JavaMail Api. \nRegards \nBackend.";
        
        sendEmail(recipient,subject,message);
    }
    
    public static void sendEmail(String recipient, String subject, String message) {
        
         //email ID of  Sender
         String sender = "xyz@gmail.com"; 

         //using host as localhost
         String smtpHost = "127.0.0.0";
         int smtpPort = 587; 
        
         //Getting system properties 
         Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 
         System.out.println("Properties:" + properties);
      
         //Setting up mail server 
         properties.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost); 
         properties.put("mail.smtp.port", smtpPort); 
         properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
         properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
         properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
      
         //creating session object to get properties 
         Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
             @Override
              protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
              {
                  return new PasswordAuthentication(sender,"*****");
              }
          });
          
          session.setDebug(true);
          
          try {
              
              //Compose the message
              MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
              
              //from message
              msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(recipient));
              
              //adding recipient to the message
              msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipient)); 
              
              //adding subject
              msg.setSubject(subject);
              
              //adding text to message
              msg.setText(message);
              
              //sending the message
              Transport.send(msg);
              
              System.out.println("Email sent successfully"); 
              
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args []) {
        //create object of Email class
        EmailServices em = new EmailServices();
        //Create object of helper class and pass the reference for our thread class Email inside it
        Thread th = new Thread(em);
        //start the thread with the help of helper class Thread
        th.start();
        
        LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> lbq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>();
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 20, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, lbq, new ThreadPoolExecutor.AbortPolicy());
        
        // Let start all core threads initially
        executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();
        executor.submit(new EmailServices());
        executor.shutdown();
        }
}
```

I want to retrieve emailData in get() method of EmailBuffer class in EmailServices class so that i can use the verified values (email id, subject, body) to send mails. If there is another better way of implementing this then please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Your (infinite) "Consumer Loop" is not doing anything useful, because you are not doing anything with what's returned from `buffer.get()`. The rest I didn't check. Please reduce your code down to the absolute minimum required to demonstrate the problem. ie don't give us all your code, just the few lines that don't work.

Comment: @Bohemian the data which is retuned from 'buffer.get()' is supposed to go to the 'EmailServices' class and I need help in doing so (i'm new to spring boot) 
I added the code to make it easy for the readers to understand the problem.